# Proper TransactionScope for nested transactions

Tags: asp.net, transactionscope

I want to set 1st transaction scope to anything (something general) and always set the isolation level in the 2nd transaction scope. Is this possible?

```
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead }))
        {
                // some service logic
        }
    }
```

The error is thrown by the second using statement :  **The transaction specified for TransactionScope has a different IsolationLevel than the value requested for the scope**.

Current error is that 1st transactionScope is default to Serializable and i cannot add new data, but in repeatableRead i can add data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
var option1 = new TransactionOptions
{
 IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
 Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
};

var option2 = new TransactionOptions
{
 IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead,
 Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
};

using (var scopeOuter = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option1))
{
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {

    }
}
using (var scopeInner = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option2))
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {

        }
    }
    scopeInner.Complete();
}
scopeOuter.Complete();
```

}

I hope it helps..

Comment: Yea, something like this i already did. It's a good approach.

Comment: I'm confused, why is this accepted answer - I tried the code exactly as it is and as expected, it leads to  System.ArgumentException : The transaction specified for TransactionScope has a different IsolationLevel than the value requested for the scope.
    Parameter name: transactionOptions.IsolationLevel